# Change the states of the button

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

How to change the state of the button from up state to down state and vice versa? For example if I click the button(in up state), it will be then change and stay its state to down state. Like toggle on/off.

Comment: By label do you mean frame labels?

Comment: I don't know frame labels. I'm referring to the label property of the button. I don't know if it's the same. The storing and removing the label is not the problem anymore i found solution to this earlier(I'll change the title soon). My problem now is how to change the state of the button?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnID);btn.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of your code is it hard to determine what exactly you are trying to do.

What I understand from your question is, you are not able to change the state of the button -  like you cant find a function to set the state of button. You can use custom skin in your button and then try this.

```
myButton.skin.setCurrentState("your_State",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a set of graphics for your button, by any kind of display objects, and then change the visible set of objects in that button's MouseEvent.CLICK listener. Also you should track current button state from within that button. Like this:

```
public class ToggleButton extends Sprite {
    public var toggledOn:Boolean;
    ....
    private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (toggled) {
            toggled=false;
            DisplayGraphics(upState);
        } else {
            toggled=true;
            DisplayGraphics(downState);
        }
    }
}
```

So, in your "DisplayGraphics" implementation you will have to switch current contents of the Sprite that's your ToggleButton. If you would implement your button as a MovieClip, you can as well change its frames with gotoAndStop(), with a Sprite you will need to removeChild() and addChild() or whatever else you fancy, that operated on the button's children as graphics.

Comment: I assigned a skin on my button. How am I going to use it instead of sprite?

Comment: I am unaware of skins, a quick research told me they are just movie clips with named states. So, for example, you can use your toggle button as play/pause button in a skin example. After all, it has two conditions, "playing" and "paused", which you can remap to "down" and "up".